# table-cell display : content wrap outside of the box

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

is there a css genius that can explain why this is happening ? My brain is burnt right now.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>
  <a href="/home/">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>This is the home page of this site</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/contact/">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>This is another page</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>

.nav { width:280px;}
.nav li {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav li a span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;

}
.nav li a span.icon {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/25/25/") no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0Ly8fxax/1/

Must be me because I get the same behaviour under Firefox, chrome and safari.

The idea is to have a <ul><li> where li's are display:table-cell. The big picture is an horizontal menu possibly wrapping the text but keeping an icon centered vertically next to it.

The content is a link with white-space:nowrap; so the 2 child inline-blocks stay together while the second inline-block content can wrap.

It does act as it should except the wrapping occur outside the <li>

The whole point of this is basically flexbox with IE support.

Comment: Generally using `table`s for layout like this is pretty frowned upon. I'd suggest trying a flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I know ! but IE...

Comment: IE 11 and edge support it so you're really just missing <=IE10, if that's not good enough then see my answer.

Comment: @Don He's not using `<table>`. He's using CSS property `display:table` and that's not the same thing.

Comment: I question the use of `display:table-cell` without any of the other typical 'table' CSS rules. I'm not sure what happens differently. It seems that if you want a table cell by itself, there is a different property that would be more appropriate and not just flexbox, though that might be a good choice.

Comment: The whole point of this is basically flexbox with IE support. The best I could achieve was with a single element in the <a> with a background-image and a margin-left clearing it but that came at the price of not being able to have :hover with an image sprite.

Comment: And for the sake of understanding what looks like a bug but that multiple browser share ( which is highly unlikely )

Comment: as for table-cell, it's the only way I know ( beside flexbox ) to have <li>s centered vertically and be of the same height as the biggest one